# Converting 32-bit number to 16 bits or less

Tags: c, optimization, floating-point, short, mbed

On my mbed LPC1768 I have an ADC on a pin which when polled returns a 16-bit short number normalised to a floating point value between 0-1. [Document here.](https://developer.mbed.org/users/mbed_official/code/mbed/docs/082adc85693f/AnalogIn_8h_source.html)

Because it converts it to a floating point number does that mean its 32-bits? Because the number I have is a number to six decimal places. [Data Types here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_data_types.htm)

I'm running Autocorrelation and I want to reduce the time it takes to complete the analysis.
Is it correct that the floating point numbers are 32-bits long and if so is it correct that multiplying two 32-bit floating point numbers will take a lot longer than multiplying two 16-bit short value (non-demical) numbers together?

I am working with C to program the mbed.

Cheers.

Comment: Are you sure you're reading this right? What I'm seeing is "Read the input voltage, represented as an unsigned short in the range [0x0, 0xFFFF]", which seems pretty clear.

Comment: `read()` returns a float  but `read_u16()` returns a 16 bit integer, you can choose which one you want to use.

Comment: So Read() returns a 32-bit floating point number and read_u16() will return 16-bit integer and the 16-bit integer will perform faster/higher?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I should be able to comment on this quite accurately. I used to do DSP processing work where we would "integerize" code, which effectively meant we'd take a signal/audio/video algorithm, and replace all the floating point logic with fixed point arithmetic (ie: [Q_mn notation, etc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q_%28number_format%29)).

On most modern systems, you'll usually get better performance using integer arithmetic, compared to floating point arithmetic, at the expense of more complicated code you have to write.

The Chip you are using (Cortex M3) doesn't have [a dedicated hardware-based FPU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_unit): it only emulates floating point operations, so floating point operations are going to be expensive (take a lot of time).

In your case, you could just read the 16-bit value via `read_u16()`, and shift the value right 4 times, and you're done. If you're working with audio data, you might consider [looking into companding algorithms (a-law, u-law)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companding), which will give a better subjective performance than simply chopping off the 4 [LSBs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_significant_bit) to get a 12-bit number from a 16-bit number.

[Yes, a float on that system is 32bit](http://coverclock.blogspot.ca/2012/12/arduino-due-data-types.html), and is likely represented in [IEEE754 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point). Multiplying a pair of 32-bit values versus a pair of 16-bit values may very well take the same amount of time, depending on the chip in use and the presence of an FPU and ALU. On your chip, multiplying two floats will be horrendously expensive in terms of time. Also, if you multiply two 32-bit integers, they could potentially overflow, so there is one potential reason to go with floating point logic if you don't want to implement a fixed-point algorithm.

Comment: Thank you for going into so much depth. My understanding is that bitshifting to the right makes the numbers smaller but the relationship between the numbers remains the same (if they're all bit shifted). Does bitshifting improve the performance because the numbers are smaller or is it negligible, especially if you consider the time taken to adjust the numbers to start with? Cheers

Comment: @JamesDonnelly: the time taken by integer multiplies does not depend on the values of the operands. But you need to take care of overflow.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly Glad it helped. Feel free to open a discussion in the comments if you have further questions.

Answer (score 1):

It is correct to assume that multiplying two 32-bit floating point numbers will take longer than multiplying two 16-bit short value if special hardware(Floating point unit) is not present in the processor.

Comment: this is a cortex-m3 no floating point unit.  the m4 does have some float support.